# GFCI wiring same as before, but no power

Tags: electrical, installation, troubleshooting

I've watched a handful of videos on installing a GFCI outlet and it seems like a nearly identical process to installing a normal outlet, which I have done a handful of times before without issue. I wire it up in the way I believe is correct (identical to the way the broken outlet was wired):

[image]

Using a voltage detector I can see that there's power at the terminals, and that the ground is connected, but there is no power to the actual outlet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that a neutral connected to the ground of the GFCI? , grounds are bare or green and should be connected to the metal box.

Comment: Have you pushed the "reset" button? Many GFCIs need that done when first wired up.

Comment: It might be a really faded green. It connects, if you want to dignify it that far, to a box mounting screw, by examination of photographic evidence. It should be connected to a grounding screw in the threaded hole that almost certainly is already in the box for that purpose. That would not affect GFCI operation or lack thereof.

Comment: @Ecnerwal That was it! I feel dumb haha. If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: As much as it looks like the inside of that box has been painted, I'd ensure that the paint is well scraped off of the grounding screw hole threads, too. Also, scrape the paint off around where the screw head sits - that's where the wire will contact the box to make the grounding connection. Just to be sure you've got a _good_ grounding connection. Without a good ground, the GFCI is just a fancy outlet.

Comment: GFCIs don't need ground to function properly. If current **out** does not match current **in** to within 5 milliAmperes, the GFCI trips. It should be grounded if ground is available, and it appears to be, but ground is not needed for a GFCI to be different than a normal outlet.

Comment: It looks like you’re in a conduit system with a metal box.  I’m guessing you either have a steel domed cover, or a mud-ring? The latter will remove the need to hacksaw off the mounting screws off the GFCI.  Either one will ground the GFCI, so you don’t need to wire a ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you pushed the "reset" button? Many GFCIs need that done when first wired up.

*And really, get a short 10-32 screw (you can buy green ones for the purpose, or green ones with a loop of wire already attached for the purpose, but you don't need to) and look for a pre-threaded hole in the box which is intended for the ground wire - the way the ground is wired currently to a box mounting screw is a kludge and not to code.*

Comment: For what it's worth, I live in Chicago so the box itself is grounded. I don't know why the last electrician decided to actually add a ground wire.

Comment: @dfitzgerald -- the issue is that you don't want undoing the box to cause something to come ungrounded.  Pro tip: get a "self grounding" GFCI or receptacle if you want to save yourself needing that green pigtail in the future

Answer (score 0):

### You don’t need to wire a ground wire with metal boxes that are grounded

I gather you’ll either be using this with a) a domed cover, or b) a mud ring and normal cover plate.* Assuming they are metal, either one will **directly ground the GFCI via its yoke and hard metal-metal contact of yoke to box** and you do not need to run any ground wires.

### Check to make sure the warning sticker covers LOAD

We have had reports of GFCIs being found with the “Do Not Use/For Wizards Only” warning sticker covering up the wrong terminals: covering up LINE when it should be covering LOAD.

This will result in the GFCI not working at all.  So double-check that.

By the way, the sockets themselves are on the LOAD side of the GFCI.  On early GFCIs, connecting to LOAD by mistake would cause the sockets to be energized *with no GFCI protection at all*.  So modern GFCIs have a feature added to them to keep that from happening.

---

* By the way, cramming a GFCI or other Decora style recep into a 4x4 domed cover will require bending up or hacksawing off the Decora mounting screws.  That will prevent reuse of the device in any other type of box.  To solve that, you can use a mud ring with normal cover, but the fit-and-finish will not be as elegant if you do.